# Interpretation of explicitly written statements

Tags: php

Take these two statements:

```
if (!is_null($var)) { ... }
```

and

```
if (is_null($var) === false) { ... }
```

Does PHP interpret these statements as equivalent?

Comment: Just my opinion, but i find `if (is_null($var))` enough self-explainatory..

Comment: Performance - No unless you care about nanoseconds. Readability: I think first is more readable since people know is_null() returns a Boolean - second seems redundant

Comment: A condition in if is self-checked by boolean, so no need to check it by any operator. The first code is more readable by itself. And nobody cares about performance with such code till it changes its complexity.

Comment: Is there any reason that you chose to not benchmark this before posting here? Did you mean to ask, "How do I benchmark PHP?"

Comment: Great, stick with your first example; it is more readable. In your second example you have mistaken "zealous explicitness" as readability.

Comment: Two issues here - Literal answer is "yes". But if you work on a team, I guarantee co-workers will look at your second statement and think "Why did s/he write it like this?", and (with enough examples of this type of thing) you will start to be viewed as that dev that writes awkward/weird code. It's redundant. Try to make your logic read like an actual sentence. For example ---> If the variable is null, execute 1st block, otherwise execute the 2nd block ---> is more closely aligned with ---> if (is_null($var)) { // execute this } else { // execute this }

Comment: I really didn't intend this question to be about code standards. Ultimately this comes down to the code standard of the team/project you're working on, so I won't get into that discussion here.

Answer (score 1):

You should better write

```
if (null === $var) { ... }
```

That should be the best performance and is more readable than `is_null()`

Comment: Surely that's *"Better you should write"* as you're using Yoda conditions.

Comment: Can you please give some reference to support your claim of *That should be the best performance*

Comment: And your claim of "*is more readable*" is a completely subjective statement. Because I find that atrocious (not only as its less readable *to me*, but the order of the elements is reversed).

Comment: How could you possibly say that it will give best performance?

Comment: Yoda or non-Yoda should not make a difference, I think. Performance comparison can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php#83588